# Initializing an array of structs, why does using struct variables not work

Tags: c, struct

I am extremely new to C. Would appreciate if someone can help understand why code in lines 13,14 and 16 does not work, but lines 17-20 works.

With the first option (lines 13, 14 and 16) I get the error

```
error: initializer element is not constant
```

What does this mean? Also, does this mean one cannot use variables of certain type to generate new variables?

Thank you.

```
// Define structure for a good
  5 struct good {
  6     char goodname;
  7     double p; //starting proportion
  8     int theta; //average utility
  9     int sigma; //variance of error
 10 };
 11
 12 // The goods H and L
 13 struct good H = {.goodname = 'H', .p = 0.5, .theta = 100, .sigma = 20};
 14 struct good L = {.goodname = 'L', .p = 0.5, .theta = 75, .sigma = 20};
 15
 16 struct good goods[2] = {H, L}; // **Does not work**

 // ** Works**
 17 struct good goods[2] = {
 18     {.goodname = 'H', .p = 0.5, .theta = 100, .sigma = 20},
 19     {.goodname = 'L', .p = 0.5, .theta = 75, .sigma = 20}
 20 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H and L are storage locations that contain data.  The statement:

```
 struct good goods[2] = {H, L}; // **Does not work**
```

implies that goods should point to H and L, or contain the same values as H and L.

Either, copy the data from H and L to goods[0] and [1] or modify goods to be an array of pointers, as:

```
 struct good *goods[2];

 goods[0] = &H;
 goods[1] = &L;
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason line 16 does not work is the same why this much simpler example would not work:

```
const int a = 5;
int b = a; // Does not work: "initializer element is not constant"
```

What this means is that you need to use only compile-time constant expressions in the initializers. C does not consider variables compile-time constants, even the `const` ones (C++, on the other hand, considers `const` variables compile-time constants).

Answer (score 2):

It means in C you can only use constant expressions to initialize an array or a structure with static storage duration.

In your example all objects have static storage duration but:

```
 struct good H = {.goodname = 'H', .p = 0.5, .theta = 100, .sigma = 20};
```

the initializers above are literals and literals are constant expressions in C, so it is OK.

```
 struct good goods[2] = {H, L};
```

but here `H` and `L` objects are not constant expressions so the compiler gives you an error.

C has a rather strict definition of what a constant expression is and the value of an object is not considered a constant expression (even if the object is `const` qualified or initialized with a literal).

Answer (score 2):

The value of a variable, even if the variable is already initialized globally<sup>1</sup> (and even if it is `const`-qualified), is not itself a constant-expression.

A pointer to a static-duration variable<sup>2</sup> is an "extended constant expression" and can be used to initialize pointer variables, so you could do:

```
struct good *goods[2] = {&H, &L};
```

for instance, if that suits the problem.

---

<sup>1</sup>Yes, I know "initialized globally" is not really well-defined. :-)  I mean, if it's a static-duration variable that has been initialized, and is visible at the point of the new initializer.

<sup>2</sup>I.e., any "global" (file scope) variable, or a `static` variable inside a block.

Answer (score 2):

If the object is static "goods[0]/goods[1]", you can only initialize with constants. So, the reason you did not get an error initializing "good H".

If you define your variable as non-static, (for e..g, in your main() or in any of your function()) you will not get this error, as the object will be treated as "auto".