# AVR define PINS & PORT in an array

Tags: c, avr

I want to define pins and ports in an array
for example something like this.

```
char a[3]={PINA.0,PINB.2,PORTC.4};

/***********************************/
if(a[0]==1) // equal to (PINA.0==1)
//do something

a[2]=1; // equal to PORTC.4=1;
```

I know this codes are not correct and want your help to write the correct one.

My compiler is CodeVision.

Comment: I think other than code you need the links to proper tutorials also....!

Comment: I am not hardware guy, but I highly doubt PINA.0 is NOT an integer value. PINA.0 is a compiler keyword and will be converted to corresponding assembly code when reading/writing a port. Therefore I think it's not possible to assign them to array.

Comment: PINA register returns integer value and PINA.0 just returns bit (0 or 1) value.

Comment: @MohammadFarahi I posted an answer for your problem

Comment: Here is the answer: http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=67368

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrote my PIN codes in pin() function:

```
int pin(int c){
bit a;
switch(c){
case 0:
a=PINA.0;
break;

case 1:
a=PINA.1;
break;

case 2:
a=PINA.2;
break;

case 3:
a=PINA.3;
break;

case 4:
a=PINA.4;
break;

case 5:
a=PINA.5;
break;

case 6:
a=PINA.6;
break;

case 7:
a=PINA.7;
break;
}
return a;
}
```

i=pin(0) equals to i=PINA.0

Comment: How does this answer your question? And even if you want that behavior then `a = (PINA >> c) & 0x01` would be much faster and shorter, no need to compare and jump and often only 1 instruction on most embedded systems

Comment: this is a sample. serialization is not regular

Comment: http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=67368

Answer (score 2):

`PINx.<PIN_number>` is a *compiler extension* and **not** standard. It's usually used in compilers for embedded systems. Also, C doesn't allow to [initialize arrays/structs with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18495108/995714)

If you need to store it in an array and *get the value* later, explicitly assign the elements

```
char a[3];
a[0] = PINA.0;
a[1] = PINB.2;
a[2] = PORTC.4;  // why the above is PIN and below is PORT?
// This makes zero sense. PIN cannot have multiple bits
```

or

```
char a[3];
a[0] = PINA & 0x01;
a[1] = (PINB >> 2) & 0x01;
a[2] = (PORTC >> 4) & 0x01;
```

---

### Edit:

It turns out you want to **access pins as index**. In that case you'll need [a *getter* and a *setter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) instead of array. If the pin indices are random then use a `switch`

```
void setpin(char pin, bit value)
{
    switch (pin)
    {
    case 0:
        PINA.0 = value;
        break;
    case 1:
        PINB.2 = value;
        break;
    case 2:
        PORTC.4 = value;
        break;
    }
}

bit getpin(char pin)
{
    switch (pin)
    {
    case 0:
        return PINA.0;
    case 1:
        return PINB.2;
    case 2:
        return PORTC.4;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If the indices are **linear** and you don't need to use a *runtime index* then it may be possible to make a simple macro to access the pins like this:

```
#define PIN_A(X) (PINA.X)
PIN_A(0) = 1;
PIN_A(4) = PIN_A(2);
int b = PIN_A(6);

#define PIN_X0(X) (PIN##X.0)
PIN_X0(A) = 0;
PIN_X0(B) = PIN_X0(C);
int c = PIN_X0(D);
```

As you can see, `PIN_A(X)` now can replace both the `get` and `set` functions above

Comment: this array looks its variables for first time.

Comment: why cares? Nothing prevents you from declaring first and initializing after then

Comment: I have to read all the time because these registers are always changing.

Comment: if so then it's even more than a must. You cannot assign the values once at declare time `char a[3]={PINA.0,PINB.2,PORTC.4};` and waiting for the array to automatically change when the ports/pins changed. You need to read it when needed. C also don't allow you to assign multiple values to arrays such as `a = {x, y, x+y}`. The `{}` syntax is only used at initialization. It's better to use meaningful macros to define ports. Why do you prefer a[0], a[2]... over names such as "LCD_E", "BUTTON2"... If it's long you can declare it shorter and still be meaningful

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler lets you to access the pins with PINA.0 then the PINA might be a bitfield. Bitfields does not have addresses.
With this statement: `char a[3]={PINA.0,PINB.2,PORTC.4};` you are storing pin **values** in the array. So, later when you write `a[2]=1` you write 1 to the copied register value, not to the actual register. If you want to have right results you should work directly with the registers, or macros.

```
//setting PINA.2 = 1
PINA |= 1<< 2;
```

you can also define a macro like

```
#define SET_BIT(PORT_NR,BIT) (PORT_NR |= (1<<BIT)) 
#define CLEAR_BIT(PORT_NR,BIT) (PORT_NR &= ~(1<<BIT))
```

and call it:

```
SET_BIT(PINA,2);
CLEAR_BIT(PINA,2);
```

However , if you still want to keep them into an array you might be able to store pointer to functions in the array and then call them.

```
void setBit(struct port_operation* a,unsigned char bit){
    return a->_port |= (1<<bit);
}
void clearBit(struct port_operation* a,unsigned char bit){
    return a->_port &= ~(1<<bit);
}


typedef struct _port_operation{
    unsigned char _port;
    void(*set)(struct _port_operation* ,unsigned char);
    void(*clear)(struct _port_operation* ,unsigned char);
}port_operation;

port_operation port_op_a;
port_op_a._port = PORTA;
port_op_a.set = setBit;
port_op_a.clear = clearBit;

port_operation port_op_b = port_op_a;
port_op_b._port = PORTB;

port_operation[2] = {port_op_a,port_op_b};

//set 1 to PORTA bit 1
port_operation[0].set(port_operation[0],1);
```